# Image upload from ASP.NET Core MVC form to ASP.NET Core Web API post call

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have both an ASP.NET Core Web API & MVC web app (MVC) projects. In my Web API, I can successfully upload the image via API call; it uses (`[FromForm]`) in the request of `POST` Image, however when I'm trying to make a call using the web app, I can see the request doesn't pass the parameters to the API call

Here's my code:

Web API:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    [Ensure_StudentGender]
    public string? Gender { get; set; }

    public int? RollNumber { get; set; }

    public string? Standard { get; set; }

    public char? Section { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Birthday { get; set; }
    public string? BloodGroup { get; set; }
    public string? PicUrl { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    [ValidateFileUpload(new string[] { ".jpg" })]
    public IFormFile? Pic { get; set; }
}     

[HttpPost]
[TypeFilter(typeof(Validate_CreateStudentFilterAttribute))]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm] Student student)
{
        try
        {
            //upload file in wwwroot
            string filePath = FileHelper.UploadPic(student.Pic);
            student.PicUrl = filePath.Remove(0, 8);

            //to upload file in Azure storage acc               
            //await FileHelper.FileUpload(student.Pic);
            dbContext.Students.Add(student);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Get), new { id = student.Id }, student);
}
```

ASP.NET Core MVC code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddStudent(Student student)
{
       ModelState.Remove("PicUrl");
       ModelState.Remove("Pic");

       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           var response = await webApiExecuter.InvokePost("student", student);

           if (response != null)
           {
               RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
           }

           return View(student);
       }

       return View(student);
}

public async Task<T?> InvokePost<T>(string relativeUrl, T obj)
{
     var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient(name);
     var res = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(relativeUrl, obj);
     res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

     return await res.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<T>();
}
```

My view has `multipart/form-data` too:

```
<form method="post" asp-action="AddStudent" class="container" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Student">
```

I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Check the [link](https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-consume-api/#upload-files) that is doing the same thing.

Comment: You should use `MultipartFormDataContent`, then post the http request by using ` await httpClient.PostAsync(relativeUrl, formData);`.

Comment: Hi Sayeed Ahmed, if my comment is useful to you, can I summarize it as answer ? Many thanks~

Comment: @Jason Pan
 Your comments was really helpful and it worked.. thanks for your time!